# How to send error message during save_post_shop_order in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

How do I send an error message during save_post_shop_order action in WooCommerce if my custom field is not valid?

**What actually happens:**

- The order page is reloaded, a green message appears: "Order Updated"

**What we want:**

- The order page is reloaded, a red message appears: "Invalid value in Field X".

```
// Save the custom field value
public function custom_save_post_shop_order($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_shop_order', $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
    $custom_field_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_billing_' . self::instance()->field_id]);
    if ($_POST['_payment_method'] == self::instance()->id && !preg_match('/[0-7]\d[01]\d{3}[-]*\d{3}[09]/', $custom_field_value)) {
        // TODO: Send error message
        return $post_id;
    }
    $order->update_meta_data(self::instance()->field_id, $custom_field_value);
    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
// Save the custom field value
public function custom_save_post_shop_order($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_shop_order', $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
    $custom_field_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_billing_' . self::instance()->field_id]);
    if ($_POST['_payment_method'] == self::instance()->id && !preg_match('/[0-7]\d[01]\d{3}[-]*\d{3}[09]/', $custom_field_value)) {
        wc_add_notice("Set your custom message", 'error');
        wp_redirect(set your redirect URL path);
        exit;
    }
    $order->update_meta_data(self::instance()->field_id, $custom_field_value);
    $order->save();
}
```